# Iterating Json Object in Jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, json, parsing

I want to know how to iterate a JSON object using jQuery. My requirement is I am getting a list from a Java Servlet to the UI and I have to populate a combo box with the AJAX response.

The above tack I already did it using struts2 and jQuery. Now I am in the middle of nowhere, how to iterate the Java List back in JSP:

```
$("#XXX option").remove(); 
$.each(data.YYYList, function(index, item) {
    $("#XXX").append($("<option></option>").text(item).val(item));
});
```

I have set the MIME type as `response.setContentType("application/json");`

Can any one please guide me how to achieve this. Please let me know if any other information is needed from me.

Comment: Please include a sample of the JSON *text* you want to iterate over, and what you need to do with it as you iterate over it (do you want to store it somewhere else? display it? display parts?). Your question is not clear. Also, if this is all client-side, remove references to java, JSP or struts2, as they are irrelevant.

Comment: sorry for the poor post : i want the data to be populated in a combo box , the values for the combo box will be coming from the database ,

Comment: Nobody can help you unless you provide a sample input and sample output. Otherwise, we would only be able to teach you some JQuery... and there's a page for that (JQuery has excellent documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example Json:

```
  "yyyList": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Name": "aaaa "
    }, {
      "Id": "2",
      "Name": "bbb "
    }, {
      "Id": "6",
      "Name": "ccc "
    }, {
      "Id": "7",
      "Name": "ddd "
    } ]


$.ajax({
              url: "URL",
               //data: "",
               type: "GET",
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data) {            
               $.each(data.YYYList, function () {
                  $('#state').append('<'option value='+this.Id+'>'+this.Name+'<'option>');
               });
            }
        })
```

`$('#state')` ---> gives the same id for select tag in HTML
Please make correct it option syntax

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the small amount of information given by Esh, here is an example that I created for the very function you listed. I have a JSON that I want to be used in multiple select boxes.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Schlogen/gGx97/)